# If $f(a)=f(b)=0$, then $f'(c)+f(c)g'(c)=0,$ for some $c\in(a,b)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, rolles-theorem

Here's a problem that I've been stuck with for a while.

> **The Problem :** Let $J$ be an open interval. Let $f,g:J \to \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable. Assume that $f(a)=0=f(b)$ for some $a,b$ in $J$ with $a<b$. To show that $\exists c \in (a,b)$ such that $$f'(c)+f(c)g'(c)=0$$

The only thing that I can see coming out of the given information is that $\exists y \in (a,b)$ such that $f'(y)=0$ by *Rolle's theorem*. I don't see how I can use the fact that both of $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ are equal to $0$ $($and not anything else$)$. We do not know *anything* about $g$ apart from differentiability.

**Can we define a function $h$ involving $f$ and $g$ so that we may apply [Rolle's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolle%27s_theorem) or [Mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) to get to the desired result?**

Also I do suspect if we're missing any additional information here $($I tried, unsuccessfully, to come up with a counter example$)$.

**Any help would be much appreciated.**

Comment: Look at the function $\ln(f)+g$.

Comment: @MariePierredeLeTetou Slight problem with $f$ never being specified as non-negative, and even specifically stated to be equal to $0$ at at least two points.

Comment: @Arthur That is not a problem that can't be worked around.

Comment: @MariePierredeLeTetou You originally said that it was not a problem, period. I submitted my comment before you edited it to a problem that can't be worked around (or at least before I saw the update). At the time, my comment was a legitimate concern. Besides, this had the feel of a problem where there is a  solution which needs no workaround, as the answers below demonstrate. In addition, my original comment was really meant as a caution to the OP, not a degradation of your suggestion.

Comment: @MariePierredeLeTetou I guess we both fall victim to the last part. I like a good rant some times, and it seems you do too. But in that spirit, I would like to point out that you were the first one to take this personally and write things not strictly on-topic. ("Don't waste my time." I'm not. No one is forcing you to respond, or even read other's responses to your comments. If anything you're wasting your own time.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let
$$
h(x)=\mathrm{e}^{g(x)}f(x).
$$
Clearly, $h$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$ and
$$
h(a)=h(b)=0.
$$
Rolle's Theorem provides that, there exists a $c\in(a,b)$, such that $h'(c)=0$
or
$$
0=h'(c)=\mathrm{e}^{g(c)}g'(c)f(c)+\mathrm{e}^{g(c)}f'(c)=
\mathrm{e}^{g(c)}\big(g'(c)f(c)+f'(c)\big)
$$
and thus
$$
g'(c)f(c)+f'(c)=0.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Take $h=fe^{g}$. Use Rolle's theorem.