# Let $f,g$ be differentiable and continuous functions on $[a,b]$, and let $f(a)=f(b)=0$, do we always have $c \in (a,b)$ s.t $g'(c)f(c)+f'(c)=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I tried to prove this with the fact "$f(x)g(x)=h(x)=0$" when $x=a,b$.

So, by Rolle's theorem, we know there exists $c \in (a,b)$ s.t
$h'(c)=f'(c)g(c)+f(c)g'(c)=0$.

Then, for such $c$, $g'(c)f(c)=-f'(c)g(c)$, so $f'(c)+g'(c)f(c)=f'(c)(1-g(c))$.

But, if we say $f'(c)(1-g(c))=0$ is true, then this implies $f'(c)=0$ because we have no information for $g(x)$.

Here is my question:

[If we know that $f(a)=f(b)=0$, then we know there exists some $c_1 \in (a,b)$ s.t $f'(c_1)=0$. Combining with this fact, I wonder if this $c_1$ is guaranteed to be equal to $c$ from above?]

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2341863/if-fa-fb-0-then-fcfcgc-0-for-some-c-ina-b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**How do we find the right function** (heuristics)

That if $f$ is non-vanishing on $[a,b]$ your equations becomes equivalent to
$$
g'(c)+\frac{f'(c)}{f(c)}=0
$$
which suggests that one should consider
$$
h(x)=g(x)+\ln(f(x)) \,.
$$
Unfortunatelly, we cannot apply Role to this function since $f(a)=f(b)=0$.

To fix this consider
$$
\varphi=e^{h(x)}=f(x)e^{g(x)} 
$$
which is defined everywhere. Apply Role to this.

**Solution:** Apply Rolle to
$$
h(x)=f(x)e^{g(x)} 
$$

I only included the first part to show how I "guessed" this function.