# Given $f,g: I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ continuously differentiable, prove that $g$ has a root under certain conditions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $f,g: I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuously differentiable, and let $a,b \in I$ such that $a<b$ with $f(a) = f(b) = 0$ and that $f'g-fg'$ never vanishes on $[a,b]$. Prove that $g$ has a root in $[a,b]$.

I have tried using similar solutions to those seen [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4133403/let-f-g-be-differentiable-and-continuous-functions-on-a-b-and-let-fa-f) and some other similar, however I haven't found it to work out given the slight differences.

Answer (score 0):

If $g$ does not have a root in $[a, b]$ this means that $h: x\to \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ is continuouslly differentiable on $[a, b]$. Since $h(a) = h(b) = 0$ by using [Rolle's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolle%27s_theorem), you can find $c$ such that $h'(c) = 0$. Can you find a contradiction with your assumption?

Answer (score 0):

Assume the contradictory statement that $g$ has no root in $[a,b]$, i.e, $g(x)\neq0,x\in[a,b]$. Given $f'g-g'f$ never vanishes on $[a,b]$, then $\frac{f'g-g'f}{g^2}=\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{f}{g})$ is defined in $[a,b]$ and also doesn't vanish in $[a,b]$. Since $f$ and $g$ are continuously differentiable in $[a,b]$, $\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{f}{g})$ is continuous in $[a,b]$. Since $\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{f}{g})$ defined and continuous in $[a,b]$ and never vanishes in $[a,b]$, $\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{g}{g})$ must have the same sign in $[a,b]$.

i.e, $\frac{f}{g}$ is either strictly increasing or
strictly decreasing. We can then conclude that if $x_1,x_2\in[a,b]$
and $x_1\neq{x_2}$, then
$\frac{f(x_1)}{g(x_1)}\neq\frac{f(x_2)}{g(x_2)}$.
But,
$\frac{f(a)}{g(b)}=\frac{f(b)}{g(b)}=0$ and $a,b\in[a,b]$.
Thus $g$ must have a root in $[a,b]$.